# Makefile appending one variable and re-evaluating dependent variable

Tags: makefile, gnu

I'm attempting to make multiple targets and include different .c files depending on the "flavor". An example:

```
 CC=aarch64-none-elf-gcc                                                                                                                                                                 
 CFLAGS=-O3 -g -static
 LDFLAGS=-T gcc_ddr.ld -Wl,--wrap=main -static
 BINARY=hello_world
 .DEFAULT_GOAL=$(BINARY)
 
 SRC := .
 OBJ := .
 
 SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
 SOURCES := $(filter-out ./newlib.c, $(SOURCES))
 SOURCES += $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.S)
 OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
 
 $(BINARY): $(OBJECTS)
   $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
 
 $(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@
 
 .PHONY: bm
 bm: newlib $(BINARY)
 
 .PHONY: newlib
 newlib:
   $(eval SOURCES += $(SRC)/newlib.c)
 
 .PHONY: clean
 clean:
   rm -f *.o ${BINARY}
```

Where the files are:

```bash
ls
aarch64.hs   cache.h          exception.c  gcc_ddr.ld  hello_world.c    init_el1.S  macro.hs  mmu_el1.S  newlib.c   ptable.S   ulib.c  vectors.S
cache_el1.S  def_exception.h  exception.h  headers.h   hello_world.dis  init_el3.S  Makefile  msg.c      ptable.hs  submain.c  ulib.h
```

If I do:

```bash
make -n
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c ulib.c -o ulib.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c submain.c -o submain.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c exception.c -o exception.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c hello_world.c -o hello_world.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c msg.c -o msg.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -T gcc_ddr.ld -Wl,--wrap=main -static ulib.o submain.o exception.o hello_world.o msg.o cache_el1.S ptable.S vectors.S mmu_el1.S init_el3.S init_el1.S -o hello_world
```

All is well. However, I expect the results of `make bm` to be:

```bash
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c ulib.c -o ulib.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c submain.c -o submain.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c exception.c -o exception.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c hello_world.c -o hello_world.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c msg.c -o msg.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c newlib.c -o newlib.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -T gcc_ddr.ld -Wl,--wrap=main -static ulib.o submain.o exception.o hello_world.o msg.o newlib.o cache_el1.S ptable.S vectors.S mmu_el1.S init_el3.S init_el1.S -o hello_world
```

But it is not. Instead I get:

```
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c ulib.c -o ulib.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c submain.c -o submain.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c exception.c -o exception.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c hello_world.c -o hello_world.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -O3 -g -static -I. -c msg.c -o msg.o
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -T gcc_ddr.ld -Wl,--wrap=main -static ulib.o submain.o exception.o hello_world.o msg.o cache_el1.S ptable.S vectors.S mmu_el1.S init_el3.S init_el1.S -o hello_world
```

Comment: You simply cannot handle Make variables that way. The simplest solution is to give the `bm` rule a recipe to build the binary. (There may be more elegant solutions, but for complicated reasons I can't test makefiles right now.)

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your Makefile because all the `.S` assembly source files are part of the `SOURCES` **and** `OBJECTS` variables, which is a bit strange. Also, declaring a phony target `newlib` while you have a `newlib.c` source file is not a very good idea.

Comment: @Beta This is a simplified example. My real workflow has many permutations where I either remove or add sources/objects based on combos of phony targets. I want to avoid making targets for each and every permutation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditionals and test the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable. Toy example:

```
$ ls
Makefile bar.c foo.c main.c newlib.c

$ cat Makefile
SOURCES       := $(wildcard *.c)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),bm)
SOURCES       := $(filter-out newlib.c,$(SOURCES))
endif
OBJECTS       := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))
BINARY        := hello_world
.DEFAULT_GOAL := $(BINARY)

.PHONY: bm $(BINARY)

bm: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$ make
cc  -c -o bar.o bar.c
cc  -c -o foo.o foo.c
cc  -c -o main.o main.c
cc   -o hello_world bar.o foo.o main.o

$ make bm
cc  -c -o newlib.o newlib.c
cc   -o hello_world bar.o foo.o main.o newlib.o
```

Note: `$(BINARY)` is declared phony to force its rebuild, just in case you just `make` after a `make bm`. It is not super efficient because if you build twice with `make` (or `make bm`) it is uselessly rebuilt, but it is the simplest way to handle this kind of situations.

If building `$(BINARY)` takes a lot of time and you want to avoid useless rebuild, you should probably consider having 2 different targets, one without `newlib` (`hello_world`) and one with (`hello_world_wn`):

```
$ cat Makefile
SOURCES       := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS       := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))
BINARY        := hello_world hello_world_wn
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINARY)

hello_world: $(filter-out newlib.o,$(OBJECTS))
hello_world_wn: $(OBJECTS)

$(BINARY):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$ make
cc  -c -o bar.o bar.c
cc  -c -o foo.o foo.c
cc  -c -o main.o main.c
cc  -c -o newlib.o newlib.c
cc   -o hello_world bar.o foo.o main.o 
cc   -o hello_world_wn bar.o foo.o main.o newlib.o
```

Comment: For ```make hello_world``` would this actually call the compile command?

Comment: Yes, it would. If there is a `hello_world.c` or `hello_world.cpp` file.